# Convert api response array to another array to pass to Vue prop

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to use [this vue flipbook](https://github.com/ts1/flipbook-vue) component and it needs a array of image urls for the prop "pages". My posts response is coming from the wordpress rest api.

I need to get the "image" property from the response array and convert it into another array of image urls. Normally I would use the posts() in computed like `v-for=post in posts` in my template and display the image like `post.image_full` in the loop..

Flipbook component:

```
<Flipbook
   class="flipbook"
   :pages="imagesArray" <--- images array here
   v-slot="flipbook"
   ref="flipbook"
   >
</Flipbook>
```

My Posts.vue component:

```
export default {
  name: 'GridOne',
  props: {
    page: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      request: {
        type: 'posts',
        params: { 
          per_page: this.$store.state.site.posts_per_page,
          page: this.page
        }, 
        showLoading: true 
      },
      totalPages: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    posts() {
      return this.$store.getters.requestedItems(this.request) <--- my response array
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      return this.$store.dispatch('getItems', this.request)
    },
    setTotalPages() {
      this.totalPages = this.$store.getters.totalPages(this.request)
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getPosts().then(() => this.setTotalPages())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript "map" function. This function takes one array and return a new one.

```
// If this is the response array....
const response = [{name: 'image 1', url: 'https://uri.com/img1'}, ...]


// Then you return something like this
response.map(item => {
    return {
       ...item,
       image_full: item.url
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined on posts when i look in the vue devtools. Sorry, i'm still learning and am probably doing it wrong. If i just do ```return this.$store.getters.requestedItems(this.request)```, I get the correct response from the api. This is how i'm doing it: ```computed: {
    posts() {
      const response = this.$store.getters.requestedItems(this.request)
      response.map(item => {
        return item.media_full
        
      })
    }
  },```

Comment: @shubhra You have to return the response on the end of posts function. 
`return response.map(item => { return item.media_full })`
Also considerate to check if `response` is a valid variable before interate it